# FCM push notification is not being shown on the active web device

Tags: node.js, firebase, web, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I've come across some unexpected issue while using FCM for sending push notifications. I have logged in on my computer and mobile (web), when I hit the button that is responsible for event trigger, the notification pops up but not on the active device. If I hit the button using my mobile, the notification pops up on my computer and not on mobile. Similarly, when I do it using my computer, I'm able to see notification on my mobile and not computer.
Is it an issue or this is how it's supposed to be?
I'm using firebase-admin SDK with my Nodejs server.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

The push notifications are only shown when your App is not in focus. If you use your App to send a push notification you won't see it there. You can still build your own logic for handling incoming messages while your app has focus using this kind of code:

```js
// Handle incoming messages. Called when:
// - a message is received while the app has focus
// - the user clicks on an app notification created by a service worker
//   `messaging.onBackgroundMessage` handler.
messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
  console.log('Message received. ', payload);
  // ...
});
```

You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#handle_messages_when_your_web_app_is_in_the_foreground).